# React-Native Opening Url in MX Video Player with Intent

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, android-intent

I am trying to open live stream from my webcams website in Mx Player via React-native I have found a good option:

> react-native-send-intent

In my code, I am using this:

```js
  PlayStream (Stream) {
    var SendIntentAndroid = require('react-native-send-intent');
    SendIntentAndroid.openApp('com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad', {'com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad':Stream});
  }
```

But this opens the Mx Video Player App without playing the stream. The intent documentation from MX PLAYER can be found here : [enter link description here](https://sites.google.com/site/mxvpen/api)

I have tried changing the code to:

```
'data': Stream and 'videoUri': Stream
```

but none of these seem to work, has anyone tried to do this in react-native? 
I already have the rest of my app working fine apart from this intent to open the stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`react-native-send-intent` currently doesn't support opening app with intent data. [This PR](https://github.com/lucasferreira/react-native-send-intent/pull/60) gives a solution and includes sample codes in README.md to open MX Player.

Comment: so why does the documentation say it can open an app with extra data :/

Comment: Thanks this seems to work perfect hopefully they merge it

Comment: `data` and `extras` are two different prop of intent. Currently openApp only set `extras`, not `data`.